# Command to be run when it is terminated by Ctrl+C

Tags: ruby

Is there a reserved command name that will be run when the entire script is terminated by the user with Control+c? For example, if I wanted to do `puts "Script terminated by user."` when the script is terminated, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
trap("INT") do
  puts "Script terminated by user."
  exit
end

sleep 10
```

Run this, and hit ctrl-c.

Answer (score 2):

`Kernel.trap` method can be used to specify signal handlers.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the other two answers, I looked up some related methods in `Kernel`, and found out that there are yet some other ways:

```
trap(0){puts "Script terminated by user."}
```

or

```
at_exit{puts "Script terminated by user."}
```

Comment: at_exit will print the message when the script ends, ctrl-C or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be a more graceful way to exit the script.  This is useful if you want to exit cleanly and make sure your script has left things in a consistent state.

http://futuresimple.github.com/posts/2012-02-24-graceful-exiting-from-console-programs-in-ruby/

```
require "singleton"

class GracefulQuit
  include Singleton

  attr_accessor :breaker

  def initialize
    self.breaker = false
  end

  def self.enable
    trap('INT') {
      yield if block_given?
      self.instance.breaker = true
    }
  end

  def self.check(message = "Quitting")
    if self.instance.breaker
      yield if block_given?
      puts message
      exit
    end
  end

end
```

Then you can write this in your script:

```
require 'graceful_quit'
GracefulQuit.enable{puts "Exit signal received..."}
puts "Control-C to exit"

while(true)
   ...
   # something that you want to make sure finishes before you exit
   ...
  GracefulQuit.check("Done.")
  sleep(10)
end
```